# Is it OK to store every object of certain class in one class array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, oop, class

Is it OK to create a class array and save every object of that class in it? I'm not sure if there is something similar to this natively in Ruby or a design pattern that accomplish this, so this is my solution for accessing every object of a class:

```
class Foo
  @@all = []

  def self.all
    @@all
  end

  def initialize 
    @@all << self
  end
end

Foo.all.each do |foo|
  # do something
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it, natively:

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(Foo) do |foo|
  # do something with foo
end
```

Comment: The object won't be destroyed if it's in an array. This will keep the objects alive indefinitely.

Comment: But to use `each_object` I'll have to keep a reference to it, right?

Comment: You have a good point. I forgot about it. I erased my mistake, thank you.

Comment: @Fábio Perez: You'll have to keep a reference to what? You can always access ObjectSpace through the ObjectSpace constant.

Comment: @Chuck To the every object. Other way, GC will delete it. Is that right?

Comment: @Fábio Perez: Yes, if you actually want to prevent any instances of that class from ever being collected, the array does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It's problematic in that it will make all instances of the class immortal — the array will keep them alive as long as they are in it. It's better to use `ObjectSpace.each_object(Foo)` (mentioned by LBg) or an array of WeakRefs that you periodically cull (this is less space-efficient).

If this is for a short-lived script that won't be using huge data-sets, or you actually *want* to make all the objects immortal and you'll be careful not to blow the heap, then there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may end up putting too much logic in the `Foo` class itself. Instead, you may want to create a `FooCollection` object.

This'll prove especially useful if you turn out to need multiple collections of `foo` objects. This has happened to me!

Comment: +1 Often I start with collection in a class variable. When my script becomes more complex, I end often in a FooCollection object. In meantime I start immediate with a FooCollection.